# Alleged Re-Declaration of function in PHP

Tags: php, function, declaration, fatal-error, redeclaration

I'm getting a PHP fatal error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getString() (previously declared in path/src/scripts/php/functions.php:66) in path/src/scripts/php/functions.php on line 111

These files are included:

1. ***index.php*** which "is" the page
2. ***functions.php*** which is called by *index.php* via `require_once`. It includes all the functions and stuff
3. ***error.php*** which is called by *functions.php* when an error in the given function appears. *error.php* calls *functions.php*, but only via `require_once`, so in this case it should not call the *functions.php* a second time

I usually know what that error means. But this function is only declared once. Also, the error only occurs when I call it in another function within the *functions.php*.

Here is the function:

```
function getString($key, $lang) {
if (!is_string($key) || !is_string($lang)) {
    $fehlercode = "StringNoString";
    require_once ("path/src/logs/error.php");
    exit;
}
$urkey = $key;
$key = (String) $key;
if (strlen($key) < 5) {
    switch (strlen($key)) {
        case 4:
            $key = "0".$key;
            break;
        case 3:
            $key = "00".$key;
            break;
        case 2:
            $key = "000".$key;
            break;
        case 1:
            $key = "0000".$key;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
global $de_Array, $en_Array;

if ($lang == "en") {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $en_Array)) {
        return $en_Array[$key];
    } else {
        $fehlercode = "NoStringOn(".$key."en)";
        require_once ("path/src/logs/error.php");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $de_Array)) {
        return $de_Array[$key];
    } else {
        $fehlercode = "NoStringOn(".$key."de)";
        require_once ("path/src/logs/error.php");
        exit;
    }
}
}
```

It works, when I call it in *index.php* like this:

```
<? echo getString("00004", $prefLang); ?>
```

But it doesn't work, when I call the function from within another function in *functions.php* like this:

```
$faqs = '<div class="zweispaltigEZ"><div class="left"><h3>'.getString("00087", $prefLang).'</h3><ol>'.$questions.'</ol></div><div class="right"><h3>'.getString("00088", $prefLang).'</h3>'.$answers.'</div></div>';
return $faqs;
```

There is nothing wrong with the function calling `getString()`, because when I replace it with hardcoded text, it works.

---

### EDIT

I "solved" the fatal error by removing the code that calls the *error.php* and the `exits`. However, now, the *getString()* function still doesn't function properly. Calling it directly from the index.php (like above) works fine, but calling it within another function leads to no output at all.

Comment: What is in lines 66 and 111 of functions.php?

Comment: Are you using `require`/`include` or `require_once`/`include_once` ?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro line 66: `function getString($key, $lang) {`
line 111: `}`
@MatteoTassinari as stated above I only use `require_once`.

Comment: The error message is saying that `getString` is being defined on both line 66 and 111 of `functions.php`.

Comment: Also, is the error.php in `require_once ("path/src/logs/error.php");` (~lines 69, 99 and 107) the same error.php that has a `require_once()` to functions.php? I could see some potential issues in a file that requires a file that requires the first file, but that would depend on how includes/requires are managed on PHP

Comment: Actually, the line number in the error about redeclaration points to the last line of the extra declaration. What line is the matching `{` on?

Comment: @Barmar His `getString` function is 46 lines, the starting `{` will be on line 66.

Comment: @Siguza Yeah, I just counted the lines. So this problem does seem to have to do with the file getting included twice, even though he says he uses `require_once`.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro yes it is. I further figured that when I comment out the said lines and the following `exit`s, the fatal error won't accur anymore, but the function calling `getString()` still won't work properly

Comment: @bendenfield I am going to say that the issue is that you are requiring the error.php file while the funtions.php is not fully loaded yet, then functions.php is required by error.php and that causes the problem

Comment: @bendenfield Try adding something like the following to the top of your functions.php file: `if(defined('MY_DEBUG')){var_dump(debug_backtrace());}else{define('MY_DEBUG', 1);}` That should tell you where the file gets included a second time.

Comment: From the code of `getString()` I'd say (and this is me assuming a lot) that error.php is just a file that shows an error message depending on the value of `$fehlercode`. Can it be redesigned into a function (in functions.php) that gets `$fehlercode` as a parameter, and instead of adding it using `require_once()` just call the function?

Comment: This could work, but it still won't get my `getString()` function to work properly. As stated in a comment above, commenting out the inclusion of error.php prevents the fatal error, but the function still doesn't work.

Comment: It is almost impossible to tell just by seeing the content of `getString()` only. We'd need to see more code and more detailed error messages to figure this out.